# My Discord bot isn't joining voice (js) error show below

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

this is the code i am using to make my bot join the server

```
if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
   play(connection, message);
                    });
```

and this is the error i get, i am in a voice chat as i have seen that is something that casues that error aswell

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (A:\Projects\JereBot\api\main.js:182:84)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (A:\Projects\JereBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (A:\Projects\JereBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (A:\Projects\JereBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (A:\Projects\JereBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (A:\Projects\JereBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (A:\Projects\JereBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since [discord.js 12.0.0](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/12.0.0), the API uses a cache. Try that:

```
let channel_info = message.member.guild.voiceStates.cache.find(user => user.id == message.author.id)
message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id == channel_info.channelID).join().then(function(connection){
    play(connection, message);
});
```

Comment: Yeah this worked to make the bot join now thanks. its just not playing the song now but i will try figure that out

Comment: No worries, think of putting the answer as useful and putting the subject in solved